# Swapping first and last name positions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help in writing the body for this function that swaps the positions of the last name and first name.

Essentially, I have to write a body to swap the first name from a string to the last name's positions.

The initial order is first name followed by last name (separated by a comma).
Example: `'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian, Dumbledore'`

The result I want is: `'Dumbledore, Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'`

But I've tried the following and I'm still not getting the right answer:

```
temp = name_list[len(name_list)-1]
name_list[len(name_list)-1] = name_list[0] 
name_list[0] = temp
```

The result is a list, which is not what I want. I'm a new user to Python, so please don't go into too complex ways of solving this.

Comment: Is your initial value a list, or a string with a comma in it? Your text seems to suggest the latter, but your code the former.

Comment: Return name[name.find(',')+2:]+", "+name[:name.find(',')]

Comment: It is a string with a comma in it. I don't want a list as an answer, which I seem to keep getting.
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by splitting the string by the comma—which yields a list—then reversing that list, and joining the list by a comma again to get back a string:

```
>>> name = 'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian, Dumbledore'
>>> ', '.join(reversed(name.split(', ')))
'Dumbledore, Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'
```

If you can’t use the [`reversed` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) (for whatever reason), then you can do the reversal manually by storing the list elements individually first.

```
>>> name.split(', ')
['Albus Percival Wulfric Brian', 'Dumbledore']
>>> first, last = name.split(', ')
>>> first
'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'
>>> last
'Dumbledore'
>>> [last, first]
['Dumbledore', 'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian']
>>> ', '.join([last, first])
'Dumbledore, Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'
>>> last + ', ' + first
'Dumbledore, Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'
```

As it’s theoretically possible that the string contains multiple commas, you should consider passing `1` as the second parameter to [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to make sure that you only perform a single split, producing two list items:

```
>>> 'some, name, with, way, too, many, commas'.split(', ', 1)
['some', 'name, with, way, too, many, commas']
```

Instead of using `str.split`, you can also locate the comma in the string and split up the string yourself. You can use [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) to get the index of the comma, and then use [sequence splicing](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) to split up the string:

```
>>> name.index(',')
28
>>> name[:28] # string up to index 28
'Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'
>>> name[30:] # string starting at index 30 (we have to consider the space too)
'Dumbledore'
>>> index = name.index(',')
>>> name[index + 2:] + ', ' + name[:index]
'Dumbledore, Albus Percival Wulfric Brian'
```

Comment: What if I'm not allowed to use the reversed built-in function, but am allowed to use the join and split methods? Do you think you can possibly help me on this? (As in using a similar approach but not using the reversed function)
Thanks kindly for your help!

Comment: @user3448498 Expanded my answer :)

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help!
What if the name was: 'Super huper, Fat'?
How will I turn it into 'Fat, Super huper'?

Comment: @user3448498 If you do `name = 'Super huper, Fat'` in above code (instead of setting it to Dumbledore’s name), then you will see it works just the same and will produce the correct result.

Comment: I made a mistake. The result I want must have no commas in between. I'm confused now, because I tried using the split() method, but it didn't yield the right answer...

Comment: If you don’t want commas, you can just leave it out: `last + ' ' + first`, or join by only a space: `' '.join(…)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need many built in functions for this

```
return name[name.find(',')+2:]+", "+name[:name.find(',')]
```