# Swapping first and last name and take initials in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, reverse

I have the following dataset containing two columns full with names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Player1':[ 'Roger Federer ', 'Alex De Minaur'], 'Player2':['Bernabe Zapata Miralles','Andy Roddick']})
```

with output:

```
          Player1                  Player2
0  Roger Federer   Bernabe Zapata Miralles
1  Alex De Minaur             Andy Roddick
```

I want however to convert these names in the pandas DataFrame so it looks like:

```
        Player1             Player2
0    Federer R.  Zapata Miralles B.
1  De Minaur A.          Roddick A.
```

Full middle name(if present) - full surname - First letter of the first name followed by a dot.

There are a few comparable questions on stackoverflow that could help:

[Preserve full surname, get initials of first name (and middle name if some) in pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417627/preserve-full-surname-get-initials-of-first-name-and-middle-name-if-some-in-p)
[Swapping first and last name positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572902/swapping-first-and-last-name-positions)

Anything would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string methods are generally slow, but you can try the below which [`stacks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the dataframe, the performs a [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) , then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) back to original shape:

```
s = df.stack()
s1 = s.str.split()
out = s1.str[1:].str.join(" ").add(" "+s.str[0].str[0].add(".")).unstack()
```

---

```
print(out)

       Player1             Player2
0    Federer R.  Zapata Miralles B.
1  De Minaur A.          Roddick A.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant solution, but will work fine if the dataframe is less than a few hundred thousand rows.

Define a function that just uses native Python list methods

```
def convert_name(col):
    return col.split()[1:] + col.split()[0][0] + '.'
```

We'll apply this to every row in the columns you want. It takes the cell value, a string, splits it into words, and then combines them like: everything after the first name + the first character of the first name + a full stop.

To apply this to the dataframe, use lambda functions.

```
df['Player1'] = df.Player1.apply(lambda x: convert_name(x))
```

This is Pandas' version of for looping through the rows. It's more efficient than for looping, and better practise, though still slow in large frames.

Note that if any of the names isn't formatted properly (for example they only have one name), then this will result in error. You can implement error handling in the `convert_name` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The real dataFrame contains over 100 thousand rows, so that would take really long, I think? And for me your answer results in an error:TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable. You know how I can avoid this error and make it work?